# Clean and optimize if

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this code in my page but I want optimize it, because it's too long. Can you show me a different way for write it?

```
public function __construct($css, $info, $other){
    if ($info != FALSE) {
          echo "Info is True";
    }
    if ($css != FALSE) {
          echo "Css is true";
    }
    if ($other != FALSE) {
          echo "other is true";
    }
}
```

This is just an example. The code has too many`if` conditions, because the fields that I have to check are different. Is there a different way to do it?

I have tried other ways but without success.
EDIT: some times the variables are empty!

Comment: Why? While visually repetitive, the code is simple, clean, and clearly communicates.

Comment: is becouse those variables is part of a function. public function ($css,$other, $info) and some time are empty.

Comment: What you want to do with this code ? Optimize that haven't any sense.

Comment: I think that is simply and clear enough.

Comment: What @JasonMcCreary said

Comment: Do you want to check if it is not false? Then you should use `!== false` .... If the empty value also should not echo any stuff you can rewrite `if ($x != FALSE)` to `if ($x)`

Comment: some one suggest me to write in the public function: public function __construc($css = false e bla bla ) i  this way when i use the instance i don't have to write False.

Comment: Ultimately, this code is so simple that it isn't worth much analysis. I wouldn't worry about a re-factor until you have something worth re-factoring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To avoid a lot of `ifs` you can use a separate function to `echo` the desired text, example:

```
public function __construct($css = false, $info = false, $other = false) {
    $this->echoIfTrue($css, "Css is true");
    $this->echoIfTrue($info, "Info is true");
    $this->echoIfTrue($other, "Other is true");
}

private function echoIfTrue($someVar, $textToEcho) {
    if ($someVar) {
        echo $textToEcho;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clear enough, but you can try different representation like :

```
public function __construct($css, $info, $other){
    echo $info != FALSE ? 'Info is True' : 'Info is False';
    echo $css != FALSE ? 'CSS is True' : 'CSS is False';
    echo $other != FALSE ? 'Other is True' : 'Other is False';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, your existing code is clear enough (and probably what you should be using) but for the fun of it, you can always make it quite short by using variable variables :-)

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($css, $info, $other)
    {
        foreach (array('css', 'info', 'other') as $p)
            if (!!$$p) echo "$p is true" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$bar = new Foo(1, '', true);
```

Output:

```
css is true
other is true
```